# Tikz: How to remove bullets from line and how to draw lines to a node without having a space

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I'm trying to draw a simple schematic in tikz and am facing two problems:

1. As you can see in the picture below, the horizontal line doesn't connect to the vertical line, where I put a node straight on the line. How can I force this line to be draw to the node without a space?
2. When trying to draw lines with bullets on its one end, the bullets appear on both ends. What can I do, that the bullets at the marked ends (in the picture below) are removed? And how can I achieve, that the lower filled bullet is drawn in the middle of the horizontal line?

[image: Wrong Bullet points and space between line and node]

My code is the following:

```
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]

\node [] (v1) at (0,1) {};
\node [] (v2) at (0,-1) {};
\node [] (v3) at ([yshift=-0.75cm] v1) {};
\node [] (v4) at ([xshift=-2cm] v3) {};
\node [resistor, draw=black, rotate=90] (pullUpRes) at (-1,1.25) {};
\node [] (v5) at ([yshift=1cm] pullUpRes) {};

\draw [] (v1) edge (v2);
\draw [] (v3) edge (v4);
\draw [-*] (pullUpRes.west) edge ([yshift=-1cm] pullUpRes);
\draw [-o] (pullUpRes.east) edge (v5);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, if this is the output you’re looking for:

```
\documentclass[11pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
\coordinate (v1) at (0,1);
\coordinate (v3) at (0,0.25);
\node [resistor, draw=black, rotate=90] (pullUpRes) at (-1,1.25) {};

\draw [] (v1) -- ++(0,-2);
\draw [] (v3) -- ++(-2,0);
\draw [-*] (pullUpRes.west) -- ++(0,-0.5);
\draw [-o] (pullUpRes.east) -- ++(0,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note, that `edge` will always add tips to both ends. Also, combining `xshift` and `yshift` with `coordinates` will usually lead to unwanted behaviour.

You could of course also use the `positioning` library with `below = of <name of the node>`and the`node distance = <length>` option, but that depends on how complex your image is going to get, really.

And the other possibility to streamline your image is the use of `intersections`.

Edit: if you need the black dot to be exactly on the horizontal line you can also use the `calc` library:

```
\documentclass[11pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
\coordinate (v1) at (0,1);
\coordinate (v2) at (0,0.25);
\coordinate (v3) at ($(v2)+(-2,0)$);
\node [resistor, draw=black, rotate=90] (pullUpRes) at (-1,1.25) {};

\draw [] (v1) -- ++(0,-2);
\draw [red] (v2) -- ++(-2,0);
\draw [-*] (pullUpRes.west) -- ($(v2)!.5!(v3)$);
\draw [-o] (pullUpRes.east) -- ++(0,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, that already helps me a lot. Thank you very much for your answer.